# Fatal Error : Call to undefined method Database::query()

Tags: php, class, oop, mysqli

I am having an error ( `**Fatal Error : Call to undefined method Database::query()**` ) somewhere in this part, I don't know where is this coming from. Because I just changed my constructor

```
Class Database{

public function __construct(){

    $this->getConn();
}
public function getConn(){
    return new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "os_db");
}
public function select($query){
    $data = array();
    if($result = $this->query($query)){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }else{
        $data = array();
    }
return $data;
}
}
```

If I changed my query to this `if($result = $this->getConn()->query($query)`.. it works perfectly.. is there anyway that I have to call the connection I would just do like this `$this->query($query)`

Comment: What did you change your constructor to, and what was it before?

Comment: `$this->query($query)` equivalent to `Database::query($query)`

Comment: Please repeat the error message with your own words. Also, tell us what the file name and line number is (it is in the error message). You need to *understand* what is causing the error.

Comment: $this->con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "os_db"); this is my constructor before.. and I need to optimize it

Comment: so my query would look like this if($result = $this->con->query($query) which works perfectly

Comment: this question is offtopic as it makes apparent that the OP needs to sleep some.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Appreciated it!

Comment: It seems you are concerned of a downvote more than of your class consistency.

Comment: Oh nevermind. I think I'll just stick to my code now. Anyway, sorry for the dumb question.. Cheers!

Comment: your sticking to a code that gives you an error?

Comment: `$this->query()` does not exist in your class, plain and simple. There's also a lot of other nonsense going on which you should be able to spot easily if you looked over the code again in detail and tried to follow its non-existent logic.

Answer (score -2):

```
Class Database {

  public function __construct() {

    $this->getConn(); 

  } 

  public function getConn() { 

    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "os_db"); 
    $this->db = $db;

  } 

  public function select($query) { 

    $data = array(); 

    if($result = $this->db->query($query)){ 

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 

        $data[] = $row; 

      } 

    } else { 

      $data = array(); 

    } 

    return $data;

  }

}
```

Or instead of connecting everytime the class is called, you can do something like:

```
Class Database {

  public function __construct() {

  } 

  public function getConn() { 

    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "os_db"); 
    $this->db = $db;

  } 

  public function select($query) { 

    $this->getConn();

    $data = array(); 

    if($result = $this->db->query($query)){ 

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 

        $data[] = $row; 

      } 

    } else { 

      $data = array(); 

    } 

    return $data;

  }

}
```

Comment: I am afraid yo need more experience with OOP

Comment: @YourCommonSense like in what part?

Comment: Like with "everytime the class is called" part.

Comment: I am afraid it is only everyday *usage* of a technology is the only way to improve.

Comment: @YourCommonSense well then I hope I improve with time :)

Comment: Sure. Since then you may start writing answers on this topic.